# How to set file association to custom .env filename in VSCode settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, file-type, file-association, dotenv

I have a `.envDEV` file name that I use for development environment variables.

And VSCode is not recognizing it as a `dotenv` file.

[image]

If I change the language mode for the file, it seems to work (the proper styles are applied, 'though the icon won't change). But it goes away whenever I close and re-open the file.

[image]

I'm trying to set a custom file association for this, but without success so far.

**seetings.json**

```
"files.associations": {
  "*.envDEV": "dotenv"      // DOES NOT WORK
  "*.envDEV": ".env"        // DOES NOT WORK
},
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 24):

By default `.env` files have a language id of `plaintext`, but vscode does something special with it to assign a different icon. The only way I've been able to accomplish what you're asking for is with an icons extension.

The [dotenv](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikestead.dotenv) extension adds syntax highlighting and the `dotenv` language id to all your `.env` variant files. Pair that with the [vscode-icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons) extensions, and it changes the icon to the gear that the basic `.env` file has.

With just the icons extension, you can use the `properties` file association and that works as well, just add the following to `settings.json`:

```
"files.associations": {
  ".env*": "properties"
}
```

Comment: I will try that! Thank you!

Comment: It's worth noting that a dotenv file is not a properties file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Answer (score 8):

With the [dotenv](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikestead.dotenv) extension this works:

```
"files.associations": {
  "*.env*": "dotenv"      // THIS WORKS NOW
}
```

Comment: Just what i needed! thanks!

Comment: This did not work. "dotenv" is not a built in type, "properties" is.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky you'll need a dotenv plugin installed

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky mentioned and a `dotenv` file is not a `properties` file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Comment: This does not enable the syntax highlighting for me. It only changed the icons. but  "properties" does. It both applies syntax highlighting and icon change.

Comment: With "Dotenv Official + Vault", this doesn't work, at least not for me. By don't work I mean it seems to have syntax highlighting, but the cloaking part of the secrets does not get activated.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to install a separate extension you can set language mod for `.env` file as `makefile` or `python` to get syntax highlighting and `#` comment support.

```
"files.associations": {
    ".env*": "makefile"  // or "python"
  }
```

[image]

Comment: This might technically work for highlighting but `make` is weird... not sure I would recommend doing this. (i.e. $ in a makefile is special)